# How to add a &nbsp; after a specific word in a text

Tags: javascript, html

How can I add one or several `&nbsp;` inside a text, after all the word(s) which are less than 3 character long, using JavaScript?

To complete, here is my (updated) code:

```
<p class="Sentence">Neque porro quisquam et qui dolorem ipsum qu dolor sit amet, he adipisci velit</p>
<button value="Go" onclick="add_space();">Go</button>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
        
<script type="text/javascript">
function add_space() {
 var elems = document.querySelectorAll('Sentence');
 var i;
 for (i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) {
 var textArray = elems[i].innerText.split(" ");
 var addnbsp = textArray.join("&nbsp;");
 }
}
</script>
```

expected result (in html) :

```
<p class="Sentence">Neque porro quisquam et&nbsp;qui dolorem ipsum qu&nbsp;dolor sit&nbsp;amet, he&nbsp;adipisci velit</p>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know how to select an element? What about getting the element's text? Are you able to convert strings into arrays?

Comment: I tried to select and split it, and calculate lenght. Messy, can’t figure it out. Select / split work. But I’d like to see how to do it well ! Maybe there is another solution

Comment: Please add your effort to the question as a [mcve]

Comment: Ok can’t right now. But will. Thanks.

Comment: I completed my answer !

Comment: I think it's more clear now ! isn't it ?

Comment: this is your expected result `<p class="Sentence">Neque porro quisquam et&nbsp;qui dolorem ipsum qu&nbsp;dolor sit&nbsp;amet, he&nbsp;adipisci velit</p>` So if it renders as html and replace `&nbsp;` with space there is no change in first text!! Please show your expected result in html mode (replaced `&nbsp;` with space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split` , `map` and `join`

Working Sample:

```js
function add_space() {
 var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.Sentence');
 var i;
 for (i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) {
  elems[i].innerText = elems[i].innerText.split(" ").map(t => t.length <= 3 ? t + "&nbsp;" : t + " ").join('');
 }
}
```

```html
<p class="Sentence">Neque porro quisquam et qui dolorem ipsum qu dolor sit amet, he adipisci velit</p>

<p class="Sentence">this is Test</p>
<button value="Go" onclick="add_space();">Go</button>
```

Comment: Interesting thanks ! I think it's close but it render like this : word<nbsp><space>word  ---- instead of :  word<nsbp>word

Comment: @Yagayente Note that based on each `nbsp` I add one more space. Because your words already has a space. Can you show me your expected result? then I'm going to update my answer.

Comment: Ok I just I updated my question with the expected result

Comment: @Yagayente Is this what you want?

Comment: why is the &nbsp is rendering itself like a text and not like a space here ? Otherwise yes is seem to be close thanks !!

Comment: I update my answer based on your expected result! ok now I'll updated again

Comment: sorry wasn't clear again, my mistake. Thanks for you patience

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235335/discussion-between-alireza-ahmadi-and-yagayente).

Comment: It work perfectly. For those who are interested : Add "\u00A0" instead of "&nbsp;" to render !

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) or the newer [`replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll):

```js
const txt = '<p class=Sentence>Neque porro quisquam et qui dolorem ipsum qu dolor sit amet, he adipisci velit</p>';

// Replaces all `\w+`, a regex meaning "word", e.g. combination of alphanumeric characters (and underscores, for some reason)
const replaced = txt.replace(/\w+/, str => {
  if (str.length > 3) return str; // ignore
  return `${str}&nbsp;`;
});
console.log(replaced);
```

Of course you should apply this before wrapping it in `<p>` tags, since `p` is less than 3 characters and would therefore be affected.

If your question was to actually find the `<p>` tags and replace the text in there, then you worded your question a bit wrong.

Comment: Consider waiting for the asker to add their own efforts before answering?

Comment: Also `\w+` means "match a word character between one and unlimited times". It doesn't necessarily mean a word. `"hello0world"` matches `\w+`

Comment: I did mention it matching alphanumeric characters, which includes digits. The regex can always be modified to only match letters if needed.

Comment: Yes it’s about finding the p tag and change the text in it directly

Comment: In that case, look at documentation or existing questions on iterating through all DOM elements of a (CSS) class (`Sentence` in your case) and on how to modify the text. Probably involving `getElementsByClassName` and `innerText`.

Comment: Ok, will do thanks